# Browser support for readyState interactive?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a web app that has to work on very old browsers (IE 8, Firefox 20, etc).

Can I rely on [document.readyState being interactive and complete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) working correctly?

Basically, I want to perform some action after the DOM loads, but perform the action immediately if it has already loaded. Like this:

```
if (document.readyState == 'interactive' ||
    document.readyState == 'complete') {
  doAction();
} else {
  document.onready = doAction;
}
```

Comment: you can find a ton of articles from 5 years ago on the subject. look for domready js libs/snips; there's 3 or 4 ways to do this...

Comment: Thanks! Interesting ... jQuery in 2006 uses document.readyState == 'loaded' for Safari ... http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.0.js

Comment: The `interactive` state isn't reliable with IE9 and completely absent on early Android. The latter browser does support the other `readyState` phases but not `onreadystatechange`. This offers an opportunity to filter it with `if (typeof document.onreadystatechange !== 'object')`. I feature test on `async` support for scripts to rule out IE9. Using `complete` seems quite cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, with AppleScript 2.5 and Safari 10.0.3, I had to use the following construction:

```
do JavaScript "document.location.href = \"" & aNewURL & "\""        
repeat 5 times
    if ¬
        ((do JavaScript "document.location.href") = aNewURL) and ¬
        ((do JavaScript "document.readyState") = "complete") then ¬
            return
    delay 3
end repeat
error...
```

Because readyState showed "complete" with the *old* URL right after the first line.